# Differential $\sqrt{1+B(x,x)}$ map in $C^*$-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, frechet-derivative

Let $A$ is $C^*$-algebra and $P \subset A$ is subset of all elements $a \in A$ such that $a > 0$ (nonnegative) and $||a|| < \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-q}}$ (norm bounded) for some $0 < q < 1$.

Let $F : P \to A$, $F(x) = \sqrt{1+B(x,x)}$ where $B : A \times A \to A$ - is sesquilinear with norm $q$, and suppose that $B$ such that $1+B(x,x)>0$ when $x \in P$. What is Frechet derivative of $F$?

Comment: Are you sure about the Existence of square root of  the operator $1_A + B(x,x)$?

Comment: Yes, suppose $1_A + B(x,x)$ is positive when $x \in P$.

Comment: Easy variant of my question is here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1835194/frechet-derivative-of-square-root-on-positive-elements-in-some-c-algebra

Comment: If $B$ is bilinear and not sesquilinear, I fail to see how you know that $1_A+B(x,x)$ is positive.

Comment: Sesquilinear also, I will fix my question.

Comment: @MartinArgerami please, look at my another topic, maybe its obvious for you :)